# Generate combinations

Tags: list, loops, lisp, common-lisp, combinations

I am trying to write a function in Lisp that generates all possible combinations of given keys and values. Here is an example input and output:

```
Input: '((key1 . (v1 v2))
         (key2 . (v3 v4)))

Output: '(((key1 . v1)(key2 . v3))
          ((key1 . v1)(key2 . v4))
          ((key1 . v2)(key2 . v3))
          ((key1 . v2)(key2 . v4)))
```

Currently, my function for doing this is the following:

```
(defun generate-selectors (selectors)
  (cond ((= (length selectors) 0) nil)
        ((= (length selectors) 1)
         (let* ((keys (mapcar #'first selectors))
                (key (first keys))
                (values (rest (assoc key selectors))))
           (loop for val in values
                 collect (cons key val))))
        (t
         (let* ((keys (mapcar #'first selectors))
                (key (first keys))
                (values (rest (assoc key selectors)))
                (rest (remove (assoc key selectors) selectors)))
            (loop for r in (generate-selectors rest)
                  append (loop for val in values
                               collect (cons (cons key val) (list r))))))))
```

For the input given above, the function works as expected:

```
> (generate-selectors '((key1 . (v1 v2 v3)) (key2 . (v4 v5))))
  (((KEY1 . V1) (KEY2 . V4))
   ((KEY1 . V2) (KEY2 . V4))
   ((KEY1 . V3) (KEY2 . V4))
   ((KEY1 . V1) (KEY2 . V5))
   ((KEY1 . V2) (KEY2 . V5))
   ((KEY1 . V3) (KEY2 . V5)))
```

However, for longer input, the output is no longer correct!

```
> (generate-selectors '((key1 . (v1 v2 v3)) (key2 . (v4 v5)) (key3 . (v6))))
  (((KEY1 . V1) ((KEY2 . V4) (KEY3 . V6)))
   ((KEY1 . V2) ((KEY2 . V4) (KEY3 . V6)))
   ((KEY1 . V3) ((KEY2 . V4) (KEY3 . V6)))
   ((KEY1 . V1) ((KEY2 . V5) (KEY3 . V6)))
   ((KEY1 . V2) ((KEY2 . V5) (KEY3 . V6)))
   ((KEY1 . V3) ((KEY2 . V5) (KEY3 . V6))))
```

Note in the output above that `KEY2` and `KEY3` are nested in another sublist. The correct output should look like this:

```
(((KEY1 . V1) (KEY2 . V4) (KEY3 . V6))
 ((KEY1 . V2) (KEY2 . V4) (KEY3 . V6))
 ...                                  )
```

What is causing this in my `generate-selectors` function?

**EDIT:** When not wrapping `r` in a list, I get the following output:

```
> (generate-selectors '((key1 . (v1 v2 v3)) (key2 . (v4 v5)) (key3 . (v6))))
  (((KEY1 . V1) (KEY2 . V4) KEY3 . V6)
   ((KEY1 . V2) (KEY2 . V4) KEY3 . V6)
   ((KEY1 . V3) (KEY2 . V4) KEY3 . V6)
   ((KEY1 . V1) (KEY2 . V5) KEY3 . V6)
   ((KEY1 . V2) (KEY2 . V5) KEY3 . V6)
   ((KEY1 . V3) (KEY2 . V5) KEY3 . V6))
```

Comment: Generally I would propose to use something like the COMBINATIONS function from @coredump and just create the input to it. The handling of the keys seems unnecessary and complex - best use a specialized function to compute combinations -> better to debug,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
(cons (cons key val) (list r))
```

R is obtained recursively and is a *list*. You are wrapping it inside a list. Try instead:

```
(cons (cons key val) r)
```

Also, when you call `append` in the general case, you expect a *list of lists*. Your base case is however not producing a list of lists, only a list.
You need to put the additional `list` in the base case around the `cons`:

```
(loop for val in values
      collect (list (cons key val)))
```

### Another version

If you don't need keys, this one is a little bit simpler. I (re)named the function `product`, following Renzo's answer, because what you are doing is called the [*Cartesian product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product):

```
(defun product (lists)
  (if lists
      (destructuring-bind (head . lists) lists
        (loop
          with product = (product lists) 
          for value in head
          append (loop
                   for tuple in product
                   collect (cons value tuple))))
      (list (list))))

(product '((a b) (0 1 2)))
=> ((A 0) (A 1) (A 2) (B 0) (B 1) (B 2))
```

Comment: This does also not produce the correct output. I will edit my question.

Comment: Ah! That was the missing link!

Comment: However!! This again breaks the output of this case: `(generate-selectors '((key1 . (v1 v2 v3)) (key2 . (v4 v5))))`

Comment: @JNevens Seems better now

Answer (score 5):

Given the fact that the previous solution is correct, I would like to propose an alternative solution. Given a list of lists A1, A2, ... An, the following function performs the cartesian product of them (A1 x A2 x ... x An):

```
(defun cartesian-product (l)
  (if (null l)
      (list nil)
      (loop for x in (car l) 
            nconc (loop for y in (cartesian-product (cdr l)) collect (cons x y)))))
```

Then the function `generate-selectors` can be defined as:

```
(defun generate-selectors (selectors)
  (cartesian-product (loop for s in selectors
                       collect (loop for val in (cdr s) collect (cons (car s) val)))))
```